# Why do I get an "Invalid handle" error using GetFileSizeEx() with files marked read-only?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, file, handle

When I use the Windows API call GetFileSizeEx() from my Delphi 6 app on a read-only file, I get an O/S error code 6 ("Invalid file handle").  If I remove the read-only attribute from the file, the error disappears.  Why am I getting that error and is there a way to use that call or a similar one with read-only files?

Here's the relevant code:

```
function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; var FileSize: Int64): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll' name 'GetFileSizeEx';

function easyGetFileSize(theFileHandle: THandle): Int64;
begin
    if not GetFileSizeEx(theFileHandle, Result) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

-- roschler

Comment: Please show a sample of code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: I presume this is Pascal i.e. Delphi? You didn't tag it as such.

Comment: @Mark.  Good point.  I added that to my post, that the code is Delphi 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check the result of opening the file to get the file handle? Obviously if the file failed to open, you're calling `GetFileSizeEx` with an invalid handle. You'll need to open the file in a read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
function GetFileSize_(CONST sFilename: string): Int64;   { NOT TESTED }
VAR aHandle: THandle;
begin
 aHandle:= CreateFile(PChar(sFilename), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NIL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

 if aHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
 then Result:= -1
 else
  begin
   GetFileSizeEx(aHandle, Result);
   FileClose(aHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In this kind of example, I would opt to use `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()` instead, then the file size can be retrieved without opening the file.